# Facebook graph API not working as expected

Tags: facebook

When I try to upload a photo using the graph API, I get the following error:

```
{   "error": {
    "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 324,
    "fbtrace_id": "Gs78FKPAclY"   } }
```

I am testing this functionality with the same code given on: [Uploading Photos and publishing Photo stories in Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads)

specifically, caption=test, URL=https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png

and the post is: me/photos.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the url field needs to be specified in lowercase, not uppercase, i.e. "url" not "URL". If you specify "URL" then the Graph API returns the error code 324.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Comment: @Demetri - you're welcome :) BTW, you should consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer that helped you.